# MatchedGeoPosition#getMatchQuality() always returns 0

Tags: here-api

In my position handler, I try to get the road match quality of the position during navigation.

```
new PositioningManager.OnPositionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositionUpdated(PositioningManager.LocationMethod method, GeoPosition position, boolean isMapMatched) {
            if (isMapMatched) {
                GeoPosition originalPosition = ((MatchedGeoPosition) position).getRawPosition();
                int matchQuality = ((MatchedGeoPosition) position).getMatchQuality();
```

But the returned value is always 0.

[Doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-common-matchedgeoposition.html#topic-apiref__getmatchquality-void) says :

> public int getMatchQuality ()
>
> Returns a value indicating the quality of the given map-matched
>   position object.
>
> Returns:
>
> An integer in the range of [0,7], where 0 indicates a poor match and 7
>   a good match.

Why is it not working as expected ? What can I do to get the real match quality ?

Comment: Is your device online, and what positioning method are you using? GPS, assisted or HERE?

Comment: The device is online (does it make a difference ? the map matching is done even when offline). I'm using HERE PositioningManager. I start it with GPS_NETWORK LocationMethod.

Comment: Yes it does make a difference depending on the device and where it is used. If you are driving in an urban area with poor GPS coverage you would observe the result you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the results are impacted by the GPS coverage and the accuracy of the calculated position.